# What driver to get SD card read to work?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ssd, storage

i've built a computer using coolermaster silencio 650 as the case. The case has an SD card slot on the top. I plugged in the usb cable for it, but it still won't detect any SD's that I plug in.

I'm running windows 7 ultimate 64. Is there some driver I need to install to get it to work? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you plugged that USB cable properly? Windows should try to install the drivers for it. Either it's broken or the cable is connected incorrectly (check device manager). Your question doesn't clarify whether any drivers were in fact were installed.

Comment: Win7 should auto-install any driver(s) that you might need or else it will notify you. *"won't detect any SD's <sic> that I plug in"* -- What sizes/capacities of SD cards did you try?  Try inserting a real SD card (i.e. no more than 2 GB capacity, preferably just 1 GB) before trying an SDHC card. Unless the SD reader specifically claims that it can read SDHC, don't bet on it.

Answer (score 2):

Often card-reader drivers go unnoticed and uninstalled for a *long time* on custom OS installs.
I took at CoolerMaster's site, and it stinks for driver-support.  In fact, I didn't find the driver for the previous '550' model either.

CoolerMaster isn't a chipset maker- as such, they used another's controller for the card-reader.  One that's likely popular with other case/PC makers.  You will have to pull the vendor&device_ID from Device Manager and search to find the exact chipset/driver on your own.  It may even be found for certain Dell models or the like.  Look [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-find-unknown-device-drivers-by-their-vendor-device-id/).

Answer (score 0):

For my case silencio 452 I found driver here:

https://www.station-drivers.com/index.php?option=com_remository&Itemid=352&func=startdown&id=3084&lang=en

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.